# Analyze Data in array, delete, then re-analyze VBA

Tags: vba, excel

As the code is now, I can analyze the DataSet and detect outliers according to values stored in LowConf and HighConf which are based on the size of DataSet. However, I can only determine one outlier in this. I want to expand the code or add to it so I can do the following:

1. Identify the MOST outlying element first
2. Determine if it is an outlier, if so, delete that element from DataSet, if not, end the program.
3. Alter the sample size (subtract 1) and analyze the DataSet again for the next MOST outlying element and loop that k times.

My idea is to make a new array that is the distance (absolute value) from each DataSet element from the mean and then find the UBound of that and analyze that in the If statements below. My question is that once i determine whether or not it is an outlier, how do I get back to the corresponding element in DataSet and delete that? If so, is there an easier way to go about this? Also, I am new to coding so any tips on acceptable format / how to clean up the code is also appreciated.

```
Sub CalculateOutliers()

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim mean As Double
    Dim SD As Double
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim DataSet As Variant
    Dim LowConf As Single
    Dim HighConf As Single


'--------------------------------------------------------
    DataSet = Selection.Value
'Copies highlighted data into DataSet variable
'Cell A1 is (1,1) Because it starts at 0 which is out of range
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    n = Selection.CountLarge
'Counts number of entries
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
 'DEFINES 95(LowConf) AND 99(HighConf) PERCENT CONFIDENCES BASED ON
 'SAMPLE SIZE

        If n <= 5 Then

            LowConf = 1.72
            HighConf = 1.76
    End If

        If n = 6 Then

            LowConf = 1.89
            HighConf = 1.97

    End If

        If n = 7 Then

            LowConf = 2.02
            HighConf = 2.14

    End If

        If n = 8 Then

            LowConf = 2.13
            HighConf = 2.28

    End If

        If n = 9 Then

            LowConf = 2.21
            HighConf = 2.39

    End If

        If n = 10 Then

            LowConf = 2.29
            HighConf = 2.48

    End If

        If n = 11 Then

            LowConf = 2.36
            HighConf = 2.56

    End If

        If n = 12 Then

            LowConf = 2.41
            HighConf = 2.64

    End If

        If n = 13 Then

            LowConf = 2.46
            HighConf = 2.7

    End If

        If n = 14 Then

            LowConf = 2.51
            HighConf = 2.75

    End If

        If n = 15 Then

            LowConf = 2.55
            HighConf = 2.81

    End If

        If n = 16 Then

            LowConf = 2.59
            HighConf = 2.85

    End If

        If n = 17 Then

            LowConf = 2.62
            HighConf = 2.9

    End If

        If n = 18 Then

            LowConf = 2.65
            HighConf = 2.93

    End If

        If n = 19 Then

            LowConf = 2.68
            HighConf = 2.97

    End If

        If n = 20 Then

            LowConf = 2.71
            HighConf = 3

    End If

        If n = 21 Then

            LowConf = 2.73
            HighConf = 3.03

    End If

        If n = 22 Then

            LowConf = 2.76
            HighConf = 3.06

    End If

        If n = 23 Then

            LowConf = 2.78
            HighConf = 3.08

    End If

        If n = 24 Then

            LowConf = 2.8
            HighConf = 3.11

    End If

        If n = 25 Then

            LowConf = 2.82
            HighConf = 3.14

    End If

        If n = 26 Then

            LowConf = 2.84
            HighConf = 3.16

    End If

        If n = 27 Then

            LowConf = 2.86
            HighConf = 3.18

    End If

        If n = 28 Then

            LowConf = 2.88
            HighConf = 3.2

    End If

        If n = 29 Then

            LowConf = 2.89
            HighConf = 3.22

    End If

        If n = 30 Then

            LowConf = 2.91
            HighConf = 3.24

    End If

        If n <= 35 And n > 30 Then

            LowConf = 2.98
            HighConf = 3.32

    End If

        If n <= 40 And n > 35 Then

            LowConf = 3.04
            HighConf = 3.38

    End If

        If n <= 45 And n > 40 Then

            LowConf = 3.09
            HighConf = 3.44

    End If

        If n <= 50 And n > 45 Then

            LowConf = 3.13
            HighConf = 3.48

    End If

        If n <= 60 And n > 50 Then

            LowConf = 3.2
            HighConf = 3.56

    End If

        If n <= 70 And n > 60 Then

            LowConf = 3.26
            HighConf = 3.62

    End If

        If n <= 80 And n > 70 Then

            LowConf = 3.31
            HighConf = 3.67

    End If

        If n <= 90 And n > 80 Then

            LowConf = 3.35
            HighConf = 3.72

    End If

        If n <= 100 And n > 90 Then

            LowConf = 3.38
            HighConf = 3.75

    End If

        If n <= 150 And n > 100 Then

            LowConf = 3.52
            HighConf = 3.89

    End If

        If n <= 200 And n > 150 Then

            LowConf = 3.61
            HighConf = 3.98

    End If

        If n <= 300 And n > 200 Then

            LowConf = 3.72
            HighConf = 4.09

    End If

        If n <= 400 And n > 300 Then

            LowConf = 3.8
            HighConf = 4.17

    End If

        If n <= 500 And n > 400 Then

            LowConf = 3.86
            HighConf = 4.32

    End If

        If n > 500 Then

            MsgBox "Sample size cannot exceed 500."

    End If
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
        If n < 50 Then

            k = Int(n / 10)

        Else

            k = 5

    End If
'determines k = number of possible outliers
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataSet)
'Calculates mean of Data Set
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(DataSet)
'Calculates Standard Deviation of Data Set
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------


        For Each element In DataSet


            If (Abs(element - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then

                MsgBox "95% outlier: " & element


        End If

            If (Abs(element - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then

                MsgBox "99% outlier: " & element


        End If


        Next element
'--------------------------------------------------------


End Sub
```

UPDATE: I have figured out the following chunk of code. This loop should work  but now I just need to figure out how to delete Suspect from the DataSet. Once it is deleted it will loop back and recalculate mean and SD and Suspect. I realize I have no code for when UBound is equal to LBound but that is something I will deal with after this. With this code, Suspect keeps showing a value of 1. I am not sure why this is nor am I sure if the DataSet.Remove(Suspect) works.

```
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To k


'--------------------------------------------------------
    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataSet)
'Calculates mean of Data Set
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(DataSet)
'Calculates Standard Deviation of Data Set
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Suspect As Double
        If (Abs(UBound(DataSet) - mean)) > (Abs(LBound(DataSet) - mean)) Then
            Suspect = UBound(DataSet)
        End If
        If (Abs(UBound(DataSet) - mean)) < (Abs(LBound(DataSet) - mean)) Then
            Suspect = LBound(DataSet)
        End If
'Defines what the most outlying value is
'--------------------------------------------------------



'--------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Retest As Boolean

            If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then

                MsgBox "95% outlier: " & Suspect
                Retest = True

        End If

            If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then

                MsgBox "99% outlier: " & Suspect
                Retest = True

        End If

            If Retest = True Then
                DataSet.Remove (Suspect)
            End If
   MsgBox Suspect
'--------------------------------------------------------
Next i
```

UPDATE: I have changed the portion a bit. I can apply this to the minimum but How can i specify the position of Suspect and use that as the range for the delete and shift up?

```
                        Dim Retest As Boolean

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then

                            MsgBox "95% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then

                            MsgBox "99% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If
                    Dim pos As Range

                        Set pos = Application.Match(Suspect, DataSet)
                        MsgBox pos
                        If Retest = True And Suspect = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataSet) Then

                           Range(pos).Delete Shift:=xlUp

                        End If
```

Comment: Why not post a self-contained sub or function? As it is, you have all sorts of undefined variables. It isn't even clear what `DataSet` is. Is it a VBA array? Collection? Range? How are `LowConf` and `HighConf` defined? The code given is too fragmentary. It is better if you can post a [mcve].

Comment: Got it. DataArray is Variant

Comment: Tangential point: there is almost never a reason to use `Integer` or `Single` rather than `Long` or `Double`. `Integer` is asking for an overflow error sooner or later and `Single` is asking for less precision than can be easily obtained.

Comment: Warning warning: `UBound(DataSet) - mean)`, `LBound(DataSet) - mean`, these don't make sense. You are comparing **indices** to **values**. These are two different worlds. `mean` is derived from *values* in the array, `UBound` and `LBound` are the extreme indices (say addresses) of the array.

Comment: @A.S.H is there a way to retrieve the value from the UBound and LBound of the data set first then I could store those and substitute them into those statements?

Comment: @A.S.H I substituted UBound(DataSet) - mean for application.worksheetfunction.max(DataSet) and then for the minima. It seems to work

Comment: Yes it works, because fortunately you are in the unidimensional world of numbers. If your data points were *multidimensional* then you should calculate Euclidean distances from the mean. anyway, now that you can have the extreme outliers, you can find their indices by using `Application.Match(Application.Max(DataSet))` and `Application.Match(Application.Min(DataSet))`.

Answer (score 2):

This addresses the part of the question about how to clean up the code. Including white space, you have nearly 300 lines of code (determining the conf levels) which can be compressed into about a dozen or so. First, define a function:

```
Function ConfLevels(n As Long) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cutpoints As Variant, lowconfs As Variant, highconfs As Variant

    cutpoints = Array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500)
    lowconfs = Array(1.72, 1.89, 2.02, 2.13, 2.21, 2.29, 2.36, 2.41, 2.46, 2.51, 2.55, 2.59, 2.62, 2.65, 2.68, 2.71, 2.73, 2.76, 2.78, 2.8, 2.82, 2.84, 2.86, 2.88, 2.89, 2.91, 2.98, 3.04, 3.09, 3.13, 3.2, 3.26, 3.31, 3.35, 3.38, 3.52, 3.61, 3.72, 3.8, 3.86)
    highconfs = Array(1.76, 1.97, 2.14, 2.28, 2.39, 2.48, 2.56, 2.64, 2.7, 2.75, 2.81, 2.85, 2.9, 2.93, 2.97, 3#, 3.03, 3.06, 3.08, 3.11, 3.14, 3.16, 3.18, 3.2, 3.22, 3.24, 3.32, 3.38, 3.44, 3.48, 3.56, 3.62, 3.67, 3.72, 3.75, 3.89, 3.98, 4.09, 4.17, 4.32)
    i = 0
    Do While n > cutpoints(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ConfLevels = Array(lowconfs(i), highconfs(i)) 
End Function
```

Then in the main sub replace all that code by:

```
Dim levels As Variant 'in the declaration part, use a different name if you want

'if n > 500, handle error and exit sub
levels = ConfLevels(n)
LowConf = levels(0)
HignConf = levels(1)
```

You could even skip the variables `LowConf` and `HighConf` and use `levels(0)` and `levels(1)` directly.

If you explained the heuristic you used, it might be able to shorten this even more by using worksheet functions such as `T.Inv.2T`. Where did these numbers come from?

As far as the rest of your code goes, a reasonable strategy would be to write a recursive function which is fed a VBA array and returns a VBA array with all outliers removed (with the basis case being one which returns the array unchanged because there are no more outliers to remove). The main sub (which actually interacts with the spreadsheet and the user) could be relatively small.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there was a way to shorten that, I lack the experience to know what to do for that. As for your strategy I will try it out and see what I can come up with. Is there a specific function that removes something from an array?

Comment: @Nick Arrays don't have a remove method so you have to implement your own way -- perhaps write a function which takes an array and returns a smaller array obtained by copying the elements that you want to keep. `Range` objects have a `Delete` method which is a more direct.